# How to sort records in MDX query when numeric expression is used with TopCount function

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012, mdx-query

I am trying to sort the Top 201 records in my SSAS cube either ascending or descending based on requirements in my C# code.

Here I a using Adventure Works Database, where `[Reseller Order Count]`  is the measure and `[Reseller].[Business Type]` is the dimension.

Please find the details below here.

**MDX Query For Ascending Sorting**

```
SELECT{
        [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]} ON COLUMNS ,NONEMPTY((TOPCOUNT(
        (Order((([Reseller].[Business Type].[Business Type].ALLMEMBERS)), [Measures].[Reseller Order Count] ,ASC)),201,[Measures].[Reseller Order Count])),{
        [Measures].[Reseller Order Count]}) ON ROWS FROM [Adventure Works] CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING
```

**Sorting Result:**

In the following result, descending sorting is applied instead of ascending sorting.

[image]

> While checking the documentation, I have found that by default the Descending sorting will be applied.

> [image]

> Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/topcount-mdx?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks

**Question:**

> My question is how to achieve ascending sorting as well as descending when the numeric expression is added in Top Count in MDX query in a generic manner?

Comment: it looks sorted to me

Comment: @ACV - I have updated the query in my question. Only Descending is applied by default even for ascending sorting MDX query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `ASC` keyword (to signify ascending order) to `BASC` instead. The B indicates that this will break the hierarchy of the [Reseller] dimension whose members are being listed.

The phrase "break the hierarchy" means that the ordering of values takes precedence over the ordering of the dimension's hierarchy.

(With `ASC` the measures are only ordered within items that are grouped together at the same level.)